# Combining 2 arrays into one array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, restkit

I'm using RestKit to get 2 separate `API`'s.  I am getting the `API`'s just fine, but **I need to combine the two `array`s into one `array`.**

How would I do this?  Here is my code, will post extra as needed, thanks!
*(`NSMutableArray *array` is the `array` that will be the combination of `hArray` and `iArray`)*

**ViewController.m**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *hArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *iArray;


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/n/?limit=200&l=%@&t=%@&apikey=111", 
lAbbreviation, tID] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){
            hArray = objects;
            [_tableView reloadData];
        };
        [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[F mapping] forKeyPath:@"f"];
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
        };
    }];

    [self.iObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/u/?client_id=111"] 
    usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *oI){
            iArray = oI;
            [_tableView reloadData];
        };
        [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Data mapping] forKeyPath:@"data"];
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
        };
    }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be as simple as writing:

```
array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObjectsFromArray:hArray];
[array addObjectsFromArray:iArray];
```

To be more specific with your example, here's how you should edit your code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *hArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *iArray;

array = [NSMutableArray array]; // new line

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/n/?limit=200&l=%@&t=%@&apikey=111", 
lAbbreviation, tID] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){
        hArray = objects;
        [array addObjectsFromArray:hArray]; // new line
        [_tableView reloadData];
    };
    [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[F mapping] forKeyPath:@"f"];
    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
    };
}];

[self.iObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/u/?client_id=111"] 
usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *oI){
        iArray = oI;
        [array addObjectsFromArray:iArray]; // new line
        [_tableView reloadData];
    };
    [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Data mapping] forKeyPath:@"data"];
    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
    };
}];
```

For clarity, I used the `// new line` comment in each line I added.

*NOTE:* if you use iArray and hArray just as temporary values, you could also avoid declaring the two properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried it, and it makes sense, but when I do `NSLog(@"Combined array count: %lu", (unsigned long)array.count);` I get "0".  So its not grabbing the items for the array somehow.  Any idea?  The `hArray` and `iArray` definitely have items in them, so its not that.  I can't tell if its some weird mapping thing with RestKit or what.

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly initializing your `array` property before adding objects to it? In other words: make sure your array property is not nil. You can refer to the first line under the property declarations on the example I provided above.

Comment: Are you talking about making sure I have you're first `//new line` of code?

Comment: Also, to add some color, when I put an `NSLog(@"1st array: %d", array.count);` right `[array addObjectsFromArray:hArray];`, nothing even gets spit out in my console for it, so obviously I'm missing something and its probably what you're talking about.  I just need to make sure I'm following what your talking about

Comment: Yes. You should make sure that `array` is not nil when you call `-addObjectsFromArray:` on it.

Comment: How do I do that?  Sorry that I'm unfamiliar with that :/

Comment: You can either use the debugger (best way to do it) or just try with a `NSLog(@"%@", array);` right before the `[array addObjectsFromArray:hArray];` line. If you get `nil`, then please make sure to call `array = [NSMutableArray array];` at some point (before adding objects to it).

Comment: I guess my question then is how do I call `array = [NSMutableArray array];`?  Do I need to add it inside the block before the line `[array addObjectsFromArray:hArray];`?  Because I already have `array = [NSMutableArray array];` as the first line per your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: You should be initializing the `array` property just once, at your earliest convenience. I'm not familiar with RestKit, but the above blocks (the ones where you add objects to you array) will not be executed right where you **see** them, but rather in an asynchronous fashion, right when you get your response from the webservice. So don't expect to have your array pre-populated *right after* your second call to `loadObjectsAtResourcePath`. Place breakpoints inside your blocks, and when they break inspect your array property before and after adding objects to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49539/discussion-between-andrea-sprega-and-reez)